# Copy vertices to floor to create outline/wall

Tags: vertices

I've got a 3D object that's mostly 0 units thin and want to 3D print it. To do that I have to give it a certain thickness but the "Solidify" modifier (Blender 2.91) created a bunch of weird geometry that I wasn't able to fix and doing it by hand would take a long time. That's why I want to try it the following way now:

Parts of the object are hanging in mid-air and I want to create copies of all of the bottom vertices of the border, then pull them to the ground to create some kind of outline (basically mapping the 3D object to a 2D plane) and connect the bottom and top vertices to create a wall.

[image]

When I duplicate the selected vertices with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> (and <kbd>Esc</kbd> to keep them where they are), then move them with <kbd>g</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>-mouse movement, they're of course all at different heights.

How do I set all of their heights to "z=0", so the same height as the 2 vertices in the bottom right of the image? Is there also a way to already have it connect the top and the bottom vertices to create the wall, even when the original vertices aren't connected (like the first on the left and the one to the right of it)?

Comment: Select the vertices, set a pivot-point at ground-level, possibly using the 3D cursor, and SZ0 scale the verts to 0 in Z, (to the pivot-point)

Comment: I already tried s+z+0 after g+z, which moved the vertices but they still didn't end up at the same level. The 3D cursor is somewhere below the object. What's that with a pivot point?

Comment: Every transform has an orientation.. scaling and rotation need a [Pivot Point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/controls/pivot_point/index.html) to define their 0 point / axis..

Comment: That worked, thanks! At first I tested "active element" (vertex in the lower right of the image) as pivot point, which moved all of the selected vertices to the same z but not to z=0. Then I used the 3D cursor instead: I selected one of the vertices in the bottom right of the image again, then pressed "shift+s+2" (cursor to selected) and set the pivot point in the drop down menu in the top middle of the screen to "3D cursor". That even moved all of the vertices to z=0, not only to the same height.

Comment: Now I only have to connect each original vertex with the vertex directly below it. Is there a quicker way than "select original, select copy, f" (for >50 vertices)?

Comment: Why don't you select all the vertices you want to extend and then use e+g+z to extrude them and move them down? Then, while they're still selected, use s+z+0 to move them all to the same z height.

Comment: I tested that too but some of the new planes were clipping into old ones and it was sometimes hard to see which ones did and which were set up properly.